# Replace/replace all operation in notepad

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm creating a notepad program in C# winforms. Please suggest me some ideas regarding how can i perform replace/replace all operation.

Comment: Any more details? What sort of options would you like to support? Case-(in)sensitivity? Also, what have you already tried?

Comment: I'm trying to search for the first index of replace text in RichtextBox.Text and replacing it. Then creating a substring from that and again searching for the first index in the remaining string but it is creating some problems and here i'm trying to do replace/replace all operation which is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine("TEXT".Replace("EX","XE"));
```

reworked:

```
var s="TEXT";
Console.WriteLine(s.Replace("EX","XE"));
```

---

Simple implementation of question in comments:

```
        Console.WriteLine("TEXT".IndexOf("EX"));
        var s="TEXT";
        var f = "EX";
        var r = "XE";
        var i = s.IndexOf(f);
        s=s.Remove(s.IndexOf(f), f.Length);
        s = s.Insert(i, r);
        Console.WriteLine(s);
```

to replace backward using simple extension methods, invert the above and use .Reverse();

note that .IndexOf(f) has a start value .IndexOf(f,start) that can be used for stepping.

Comment: This thing works well in replace all but what about if we want to replace indivisual strings one by one by findnext like in actual notepad.

Comment: @VIKRAM: see above for some quick ideas on how to implement one-by-one.

Comment: I'm not claiming this is the most efficient, but it should be fine for small requirements.  i.e. string is an immutable type, so each insert / remove / replace creates an entirely new string.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to use RegEx for such a scenario. Perhaps helps this article http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/string/regex/article.php/c2791

It's about search/replace mechanisms by using RegEx

Thorsten

Answer (score 1):

You might first emulate Ctrl+H shortcuts to show Replace dialog, and then use PInvoke to get the windows handle of the edit controls of "Find what" and "Replace with"; finally change the text of the two edit controls, and emulate the button click "Replace All".

Possible API used include:

```
GetWindowText()
SetWindowText()
SetForeGroundWindow()
SendKeys.Send()
```